# Composition factors of intersection of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, filtrations

For simplicity we assume that $R$ is an Artinian ring, such that any finitely generated $R$-modul has a composition series. To such an $R$-modul $M$ we associate the set of composition factors $C(M)$. We consider $C(M)$ as a multiset with respect to the multiplicities of the composition factors.

Then let $M_1, M_2 \subset M$ be submodules. Do we have $C(M_1 \cap M_2)=C(M_1) \cap C(M_2)$ (considered as intersection of multisets)?

Comment: Usually "has a composition series" means "has a *finite* composition series." In that case, assuming $R$ artinian is not enough to make *all* $R$ modules have composition series. Even if one has some broader definition of composition series that allows for infinite chains I am not sure the Artinian condition on $R$ is enough to guarantee all modules have such a series.  As far as I know assuming $R$ Artinian is only enough to ensure $R_R$ has a composition series.

Comment: If $R$ is artinian ($R$ commutative), then every $R$-module is artinian and noetherian. That is equivalent to have a finite composition series.

Comment: that is false.  For a field $F$, and infinite dimensional F module is neither Artinian nor Noetherian.

Comment: Sorry you are right. Forgot to add „finitely generated“.

Comment: that changes things substantially then. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ZZ}{\mathbb{Z}}$The inclusion $C(M_1 \cap M_2) \subseteq C(M_1) \cap C(M_2)$ may well be proper.

Suppose $R$ has two non-isomorphic irreducible modules $S, T$, and let $S_{1}, S_{2}$ be two copies of $S$. Consider
$$
M = S_{1} \oplus T \oplus S_{2},
\quad
M_{1} = S_{1} \oplus T,
\quad
M_{2} = T \oplus S_{2}.
$$

As $R$ you may take the complex group algebra of a non-trivial finite group, for instance.